# How to pass List in sql query

Tags: java, sql

I have of values (`1, 2, 3`, for example), and I want to pass that list to a SQL query:

```
"select name from tbl where id in" + list
```

How might I achieve this?

Comment: what are you using to construct your sql?

Answer (score 12):

you have to put your list directly to sql statement

example:

```
String sql="select name from tbl where id in ("+StringUtils.join(list, ',')+")";
Statement st=connection.createStatement();
st.execute(sql);
```

Comment: With Java 8 you can use `String.join(",", list)`, however this solution is not appropriate for String parameters.

Comment: This code had a security issue. Because the values are not escaped, you can have SQL injection.

Answer (score 10):

I see in your reply to a comment that you're using HQL. If that's the case, the Hibernate folks make this one easy for you, in the query, just specify:

```
where id in (:ids)
```

and then use `setParameterList("ids", list)` passing your list. Hibernate will do all the expansion for you!

Answer (score 2):

The SQL syntax is:

```
select name from tbl where id in (1,2,3)
```

All you have to do is build the comma separated list of items and insert it in the string.

Oh and the obligatory sql string building warning: don't!

Answer (score 1):

it depends on how you are constructing your sql.  If you are constructing it yourself (bad idea) you need to do make the sql look like -

`... where id in (1,2,3)...`

Since in your comment you specify hibernate hql, something like -

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("from User where id in :ids ");
query.setParameter("ids", idsList);
List list = query.list();
```

should get you started.  Note `User` is the name of the Object you mapped to the table you want to query.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the list in as a comma seperated list and use a split function to split it into a temporary table variable.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split (@sep char(1), @s varchar(512))
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN (
    WITH Pieces(pn, start, stop) AS (
      SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT pn + 1, stop + 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s, stop + 1)
      FROM Pieces
      WHERE stop > 0
    )
    SELECT pn,
      SUBSTRING(@s, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 512 END) AS s
    FROM Pieces
  )
```

Comment: Talk about hunting rabbits with tactical nukes... Or using Microsoft's reporting server, same thing basically.

Comment: I think I had misunderstood the question as being "how do I pass this list into a stored procedure". My bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can write code like and then pass uuidsWithRequiredPattern to SQL.
Here in below example I had a requirement to have a uuids prefixed with single quote , suffixed with single quote and delimited with comma.

```
List<UUID> uuidList = Arrays.asList("581394be-6a27-11ea-bc55-0242ac130003","681394be-6a27-11ea-bc55-0242ac130003")
String uuidsWithRequiredPattern = uuidList.stream()
                .map(UUID::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(",", "'", "'"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a long time past but this was the page that returned when I looked for a solution to exactly this problem. It seems that all answers are not perfect for one reason or another (including the possibility of SQL injection which is a real concern).So, here's my solution:-

```
/**
 * Checks if this range exists in the database already.
 * If it does, it will return the original name.
 * @param products the list of product names to check
 * @return  The range's name in the database
 * @throws SQLException if SQL fails
 *   (or if it exists but with multiple names)
 */
private String getOriginalName(final List<String> products)throws SQLException {
  if (products.isEmpty()) {
    throw new SQLException("Cannot check an empty list");
  }
  try (Connection connection = ConnectionPoolConfigRulesUtils.getConnection();
      PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareCall(
          "SELECT [rangeName] FROM [dbo].[products] WHERE [productName] IN ("
          + repeatString("?", ", ", products.size()) + ") GROUP BY [rangeName]")) {
    int fieldNo = 1;  //NOPMD DU anomaly
    for (final DbProduct product: products) {
      statement.setInt(fieldNo++, product.getId());
    }
    try (ResultSet rset = statement.executeQuery()) {
      final String rangeName;
      if (rset.next()) {
        //Get the first range name
        rangeName = Nz.nz(rset.getString("rangeName"));
      } else {
        //There isn't one so return empty string
        rangeName = "";
      }
      if (rset.next()) {
        //But, if there are multiple ranges, this is an error so treat it as such
        throw new SQLException("The products you are trying to save exist already in the dabase under more than one range. "
            + "Cannot process the change");
      }
      return rangeName;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this here in case someone stumbles upon it - like me.
The easy way to parameterize the list to be used in the "IN" clause is to use the STRING_SPLIT function.

Declare @FirstNamesList nvarchar(100) = 'Mark,John,Sara'
Select * from STRING_SPLIT(@FirstNamesList, ',')

https://www.pragimtech.com/blog/sql-optimization/sql-server-select-where-in-list/

Answer (score -1):

```
private static String sqlFormatedList(List<String> list){
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     sb.append("('");
     for (String i : list){
       sb.append(i+"','");
     }
     sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() -1);
     sb.deleteCharAt(sb.lastIndexOf(","));
     sb.append(")");
     return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Completely vulnerable to SQL injection, and doesn't take strings with single quotes into account.