# SQL query for arraylist variable using IN clause

Tags: java, mysql

How to get the SQL query

```
ArrayList<String> KeysTest=new ArrayList<>();     
   for (TimelineResponse.TimelineJourney t : ((TimelineResponse) ((QueryClusterResponse) result).getResponse()).getJourneys()){
            KeysTest.add(t.getKey());
        }

"SELECT id ,event FROM CALL WHERE id IN '"+ KeysTest + "' AND  cost > 5000 ;";
```

So basically the above result of arraylist is being as variable in the IN clause of the query.How can it be used as I am getting error.
Note: id in the db is varchar.

Comment: `IN ( 'a', 'list', 'of', 'values' )`

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095921/how-to-pass-list-in-sql-query

Comment: You can't really bind a `List` of strings in Java directly to a prepared statement using pure JDBC.  But, JPA/Hibernate can handle this.  Are you using JPA, or pure JDBC?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot bind the list in JDBC directly to to prepared statement using JDBC it can only be done in HQL directly.
If you want to use JDBC prepare statement directly you can use StringUtils or String like

```
StringUtils.join(list, ',')
```

Or for Java 8 Onward

```
String.join(",", list)
```

If you are using HQL then it's simple you can just place the list in param and HQL will handle it for you like.

```
where key in (:list)
OR
setParameterList("key", list)
```

hope it will help.